# fade in fade out 2 items at a time with pagination

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have jquery pagination code working. I want to add fade in fade out for two items at a time.

```
<ul class="paging">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
    <li>10</li>
</ul>
```

Here is my demo.

http://jsfiddle.net/squidraj/6KRez/2/

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply the `.fadeIn()` and `.fadeOut()` to the `<ul class="paging">` instead of the `<li>`. This is because if you do `$('li').fadeIn()`, jQuery is sequentially applying the *fade in* animation to each element. If you were to do `$('ul').fadeIn()`, then jQuery will apply *fade in* animation to the entire `<ul>`, including the `<li>` elements, which in your case, only 2 is ever shown at a time. So....

Instead of just:

```
// show/hide the appropriate regions 
selector.children().hide();
selector.children(".simplePagerPage" + options.currentPage).show();
```

You need to do this:

```
$('ul.paging').fadeOut(400, function() {
     // finished fading out animation
     //hide and show relevant links
     selector.children().hide();
     selector.find(".simplePagerPage" + clickedLink).show();
}).fadeIn();
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/amyamy86/gpmSP/

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks.just one thing is it possible to add the automatic fade in fade out when the page loads.I mean without clicking(I want to keep this option too) can it be a continuous fade in fade out.Thanks.

Comment: @Raj To get it to *fade in* on load, simply have `$('ul.paging').fadeIn();` inside your `$(document).ready(function() { ... });`. You might want to have the `<ul class="paging">` initially hidden in order to have a smooth *fade in* animation...since you don't want the list to show and all of a sudden disappear and fade in slowly.

Comment: Thanks.I did that and now nothing is showing.Also on page load the quickpager function is working.Is it easier to call the quickpager function with an interval.not sure though.

Comment: @Raj You can just modify `$("ul.paging").quickPager();` to be `$("ul.paging").quickPager().fadeIn();` See: http://jsfiddle.net/amyamy86/QVntu/